# How to get sum of one day and sum of last three days in single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a statistical table like this:

```
date | stats
-------------
10/1 | 2
10/1 | 3
10/1 | 2
10/2 | 1
10/3 | 3
10/3 | 2
10/4 | 1
10/4 | 1
```

What I want is three columns:

1. Date
2. sum(stats) of Date
3. sum(stats) of last three days before Date

I know I can use window function to handle the 2nd column, but I cannot handle 2nd and 3rd at the same time.

What should I do to archive this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are we guaranteed that there is data on each day (as in the example data)?

Comment: @GordonLinoff In my situation it is true. What should we do if it is not ?

Comment: . . I would use `generate_series()` to generate the results.  If you ask another question, I can provide an answer to that (reference this one when you do).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hello, this is my question, could you please share your opinions with me? Thanks:D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066780/how-to-get-count-of-one-day-and-count-of-last-three-days-in-single-query

Answer (score 5):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select date, sum(stats) as day_stats,
       sum(sum(stats)) over (order by date rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding) as day_stats_3
from t
group by date
order by date;
```

Comment: Great! I was disappointed when I found it impossible to use range between to indicate the date range, but we can use rows between after group by! Thank you very much!

Comment: You always comes up with a better answer, nice one!

Comment: `between 3 preceding and 1 preceding` will only work if you have 1 row per day. You may want to aggregate data to single values per day first. Then use the query.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko . . . Check the `group by`.  It will work if the data has *at least* one row per day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated query:

```
SELECT s.date,sum(s.stats) as today_sum,
       (SELECT sum(t.stats) FROM YourTable t
        where t.date between s.date - 2 and s.date) as sum_3days
FROM YourTable s
GROUP BY s.date
```